# Extract a substring from a lengthy string Using Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to find/extract the substring from a very big string. Here the issue is the substring might reappear/repeats. Can someone please help with it.

*Actual String:*

```
Shell/Retrieve/force-app-temporary/main/default/classes/Account.cls-meta.xml
and
Shell/Retrieve/force-app/main/default/classes/Account.cls-meta.xml
differ Files
Shell/Retrieve/force-app-temporary/main/default/pages/Contact.cls-meta.xml
and
Shell/Retrieve/force-app/main/default/pages/Contact.cls-meta.xml
differ Files
Shell/Retrieve/force-app-temporary/main/default/Layout/Lead.cls-meta.xml
and Shell/Retrieve/force-app/main/default/Layout/Lead.cls-meta.xml
differ Files...
```

*Expected Substring:*

Find the substring which starts after 'default/' and ends with immediate '/'.
For Example, in the above String, it should return as below

```
classes
classes
pages
pages
Layout
Layout
```

I have tried below and it's not working.

```
Substrings=$(sed -n "s/.*\ default/\(.*\)/\.com.*/\\1/p" <<< $Actual_String)
```

Comment: Post a code you run. No one can guess it

Comment: don't mess with `Sustring=$()` until  you get the basic `sed` working ;-) I also think you'll need a trailing `g` (for global) to process more than 1 match per "line". Good luck.

Comment: Your example has asterisks that your output does not include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's almost it:

```
sed -n 's@.*/default/\([^/]*\).*@\1@p'
```

You can use any character in `s` command in `sed`. I use `@` here, `s@EXP@REP@`, so that `/` doesn't mix.

I match `.*` everything then `/default/` then I remember `\(` `\)`  `[^/]*` any zero or more characters up until `^/` a slash. Then I match the rest of the string with `.*`. The whole line get's substituted for what get's remembered.